# spring neo4j getting exception

Tags: spring, neo4j

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'neo4jTemplate' defined in class org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.neo4jTemplate() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingInfrastructure' defined in class org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.MappingInfrastructureFactoryBean org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.mappingInfrastructure() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'typeRepresentationStrategyFactory' defined in class org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.typerepresentation.TypeRepresentationStrategyFactory org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.typeRepresentationStrategyFactory() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringRestGraphDatabase.getAllLabelNames()Ljava/util/Collection;
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.neo4jTemplate() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingInfrastructure' defined in class org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.MappingInfrastructureFactoryBean org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.mappingInfrastructure() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'typeRepresentationStrategyFactory' defined in class org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.typerepresentation.TypeRepresentationStrategyFactory org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.typeRepresentationStrategyFactory() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringRestGraphDatabase.getAllLabelNames()Ljava/util/Collection;


    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingInfrastructure' defined in class org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.MappingInfrastructureFactoryBean org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.mappingInfrastructure() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'typeRepresentationStrategyFactory' defined in class org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.typerepresentation.TypeRepresentationStrategyFactory org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.typeRepresentationStrategyFactory() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringRestGraphDatabase.getAllLabelNames()Ljava/util/Collection;
    ... 4 more


Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.MappingInfrastructureFactoryBean org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.mappingInfrastructure() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'typeRepresentationStrategyFactory' defined in class org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.typerepresentation.TypeRepresentationStrategyFactory org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.typeRepresentationStrategyFactory() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringRestGraphDatabase.getAllLabelNames()Ljava/util/Collection;


    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'typeRepresentationStrategyFactory' defined in class org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.typerepresentation.TypeRepresentationStrategyFactory org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.typeRepresentationStrategyFactory() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringRestGraphDatabase.getAllLabelNames()Ljava/util/Collection;


    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.typerepresentation.TypeRepresentationStrategyFactory org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.typeRepresentationStrategyFactory() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringRestGraphDatabase.getAllLabelNames()Ljava/util/Collection;


    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringRestGraphDatabase.getAllLabelNames()Ljava/util/Collection;
    ... 4 more
```

I am getting this exception,my configuration is :

```
compile("org.neo4j:neo4j-community:2.0.3")

compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j-rest:3.1.2.RELEASE'

compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j:3.1.2.RELEASE'
```

Comment: So...what's the question?

Comment: why i am getting this exception?is there anything missing from my side or there is something missing in  my configuration.I just want to get rid of this exception.
I think its because of some version problems but could not get right configuration