# spring-data-neo4j how to use in grails

Tags: spring, grails, neo4j

I am looking for using spring-data-neo4j in my grails project.can i find some example somewhere?

I have tried but it is giving me error regarding neo4j database version i.e. set allow_auto_upgrade=true but i am not getting the file where to specify this option in grails.

Comment: how do you define the neo4j connection in your app?

Comment: I have posted an another question regarding the error i am getting
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25139680/spring-neo4j-getting-exception

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25175834/spring-data-neo4j-version-issue 

this is also a related question