# spring data neo4j version issue

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am trying to use spring-data-neo4j in my grails project but there are so many version conflicting.

I am using following dependency

compile `org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j-rest:3.1.2.RELEASE`

**then if i run my neo4j server 2.1.2 then it is giving me error**

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'neo4jMappingContext' defined in class org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    ... 4 more
```

**and if i run 1.8.3 neo4j server then it seems that it connects to server but again getting error**

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'typeRepresentationStrategyFactory' defined in class org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.typerepresentation.TypeRepresentationStrategyFactory org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.typeRepresentationStrategyFactory() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RestResultException: expected START or CREATE
"MATCH (ref:ReferenceNode {name:{name}}) RETURN ref"
 ^ at
SyntaxException
```

please let me know what i am missing or if someone could tell me exact versions which i should use.

**Buildconfig.config :**

```
//grails.plugin.location."neo4j" = "../grails-data-mapping/grails-plugins/neo4j"
grails.servlet.version = "3.0" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.work.dir = "target/work"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
grails.server.port.http = 7575
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"

grails.project.fork = [
    // configure settings for compilation JVM, note that if you alter the Groovy version forked compilation is required
    //  compile: [maxMemory: 256, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],

    // configure settings for the test-app JVM, uses the daemon by default
    test: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],
    // configure settings for the run-app JVM

    // TODO: workaround, for Neo4j plugin forked mode is currently not working. Reason: Neo4jSpringConfigurer is using
    //    "as Classs" which causes ClassLoader issues
    run: false, //[maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: true, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the run-war JVM
    war: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the Console UI JVM
    console: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256]
]

grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" 
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        excludes 'xml-apis', 'netty', 'stax-api', 'slf4j-jdk14','log4j-over-slf4j', 'logback-classic'
        // uncomment to disable ehcache
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "warn" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
    legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility

    repositories {
        inherits true

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        mavenLocal()
        grailsCentral()
        mavenCentral()

        // uncomment the below to enable remote dependency resolution
        // from public Maven repositories
        //flatDir name:'myRepo', dirs:'/abc/def'
        mavenRepo 'http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/releases/'
    }

    neo4jVerison="1.9.8"
    dependencies {

        //compile("org.neo4j:neo4j-community:2.0.0-M06")

        //compile(group: 'org.neo4j', name: 'neo4j', version: "$neo4jVersion")
        //compile(group: 'org.neo4j.app', name: 'neo4j-server', version: "$neo4jVersion", classifier: 'static-web')


        // this is required if DataSource.groovy uses url = "jdbc:neo4j:mem"
        //runtime(group:"org.neo4j", name:"neo4j-kernel", version:neo4jVerison)

        // next four lines are required if you're using embedded/ha *and* you want the webadmin available
        //compile(group:"org.neo4j.app", name:"neo4j-server", version:neo4jVerison)

        // grails dependencies do not properly support maven classifiers, therefor we'll copy that
        // dependency to lib directory
        //runtime(group:"org.neo4j.app", name:"neo4j-server", version:neo4jVerison, classifier:"static-web")

        //runtime('com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:1.9')
        //runtime('com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:1.9')

        // add graphviz capabilities
        //compile(group:"org.neo4j", name:"neo4j-graphviz", version: neo4jVerison)
        //runtime (group:"org.neo4j", name:"neo4j-shell", version: neo4jVerison)

        // uncomment following line if type=rest is used in DataSource.groovy
        //compile 'org.neo4j:neo4j-rest-graphdb:2.0.0-M06'

        /*compile 'org.springframework:spring-core:3.1.0.RELEASE'

        compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:3.0.0.RELEASE'

        compile 'org.springframework:spring-beans:3.0.2.RELEASE'

        compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j:1.1.0.RELEASE'*/

        compile 'javax.validation:validation-api:1.0.0.GA'

        //compile 'org.neo4j:neo4j:2.0.3'

        compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j-rest:3.1.2.RELEASE'

        //compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j:3.1.2.RELEASE'

        test "org.spockframework:spock-grails-support:0.7-groovy-2.0"
    }

     plugins {
         //compile ":neo4j:2.0.0-M02"
         compile ":scaffolding:2.0.1"
         runtime ":jquery:1.10.2.2"
         runtime ":resources:1.2.1"
         test(":spock:0.7") {
             exclude "spock-grails-support"
         }
         // compile ":geb:0.9.0-RC-1"

         // Uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable additional resources capabilities
         //runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0"
         //runtime ":cached-resources:1.0"
         //runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.4"

         build ":tomcat:7.0.50"
//         compile ':cloud-support:1.0.8'
//         compile ':webxml:1.4.1'
     }
}
```

**and resources.xml for spring set up**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:neo4j="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j/spring-neo4j-2.2.xsd">

    <!-- REST Connection to Neo4j server -->
    <bean id="graphDatabaseService"
        class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringRestGraphDatabase">
        <constructor-arg value="http://localhost:7474/db/data" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Neo4j configuration (template) -->
    <neo4j:config graphDatabaseService="graphDatabaseService" />

    <!-- Package w/ automagic repositories -->
    <neo4j:repositories base-package="sample" />


</beans>
```

i am developing in grails and using neo4j 2.1.2 version which is running on localhost:7474 and i am using rest service for data base connection

so for neo4j 2.1.2 i am getting following  exception.

```
14 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'communityCentreRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'neo4jTemplate' while setting bean property 'neo4jTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'neo4jTemplate' defined in class org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.neo4jTemplate() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'neo4jMappingContext' defined in class org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'communityCentreRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'neo4jTemplate' while setting bean property 'neo4jTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'neo4jTemplate' defined in class org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.neo4jTemplate() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'neo4jMappingContext' defined in class org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'neo4jTemplate' defined in class org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.neo4jTemplate() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'neo4jMappingContext' defined in class org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.neo4jTemplate() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'neo4jMappingContext' defined in class org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'neo4jMappingContext' defined in class org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    ... 4 more
```

Comment: If you don't share your config and the full exception traces it's impossible to figure out what happened there.

Comment: The second error is because SDN 3.1.2 only supports Neo4j 2.x (or rather 2.1+) (Cypher syntax changed)

Comment: i have updated my question with stack trace

Comment: i checked it for 2.0.4 version of neo4j,but still getting same error.

Comment: finally solved,i think some grails dependency issue,created new project and everything works!!!